# How can I add a gallery of photos to the Big Cartel NEAT Theme?

Tags: themes, product, photos, neat, bigcartel

I'm using the Big Cartel NEAT theme and on the Product page, it has one main photo and the product info next to it.
Page: http://twicedrunk.bigcartel.com

Any secondary photos are displayed (HUGE) underneath and it looks ridiculous.
I'd like to set up a gallery type situation with one main photo and secondary photos underneath like eBay (and every other normal site for that matter!).
Any tricks?
I've googled and searched for an answer but can't find it anywhere. 
I have very little programming knowledge.
Appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Neat theme for Big Cartel now supports a small thumbnail gallery / click-to-open lightbox for product images. See here: http://neatdemo.bigcartel.com/product/lightbox-for-secondary-images